# SQLite: How can I update a column with a value that is the difference between two rows of another column?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

How can I update a column with a value that is the difference (in percent) between two rows of another column?

from:

```
 y | coeff | decreased %
---|-------|------------
15 | 1.35  |
16 | 1.22  |
17 | 1.14  |
18 | 1     |
```

to:

```
 y | coeff | decreased %
---|-------|------------
15 | 1.35  |
16 | 1.22  |  9.629
17 | 1.14  |  6.557
18 | 1     | 12.280
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this `UPDATE` that gets the previous value of `coeff` even if the ids are not continuous:

```
update tablename
set decreased = 100.0 * (1.0 - coeff / (
    select t.coeff from tablename t
    where t.y = (select max(p.y) from tablename p where p.y < tablename.y)
  )
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ptEvUFYMWkJmHivAXp4Zkc/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'll do like this:

```
update tbl a
set dec_p  = select (a.coeff-b.coeff)/a.coeff as dec
             from a left join tbl b on (a.y=b.y+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your `y` is indeed sequential with no gaps, then use `left join`:

```
select t.*, 100 - (t.coeff * 100.0 / tprev.coeff) as decreased
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.y = t.y - 1;
```